# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in

Tags: node.js, angular

I know that the question related to the `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in...` has been asked many times here. But, I think it is quiet interesting situation here
that I am trying to describe below:

I having node installed on 2 machines running Ubuntu 16.10 and Ubuntu 17.04.

### 1. On ubuntu 16.04

Node is installed through these command lines:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

### 2. On ubuntu 17.04

Ubuntu 17.04 is already with a new version of node. The installation is done through

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

### 3. What is in common between the 2 machines?

#### 3.1. The version of node and npm are:

```
node -v
# v7.10.0

npm -v
# 4.2.0
```

#### 3.2. The angular4 application is created through @angular/cli

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-app
```

#### 3.3. A repo on githbub for the angular4 application with docker

The both machine are using the same repo [angular4-on-nginx-with-docker](https://github.com/mappedinn/angular4-on-nginx-with-docker)

### 4. What is the difference???

#### 4.1. On Ubuntu 16.10

```
$ ng build --prod 

Hash: 64b40519b4565aa62e0b                                                              
Time: 10106ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.71b130084c52939ca448.bundle.js (polyfills) 177 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.e81f19d3f6b27a436c79.bundle.js (main) 1.09 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 69 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.f7457d5ac1e9743fd76f.bundle.js (vendor) 849 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.18e445e37a0efd4dcfa2.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/amine/DockerProjects/tt/nginx/frontend/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

**PS:** `./src/main.ts` is:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

#### 4.2. On Ubuntu 17.04

```
$ ng build --prod 
Hash: ab00cb280399614d6ea9                                                              
Time: 16640ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.71b130084c52939ca448.bundle.js (polyfills) 177 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.97abdc47ac3699c01fa5.bundle.js (main) 5.27 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 69 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.0a8aa978ae08e1954b1c.bundle.js (vendor) 1.89 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.3da3f5efaa0601772495.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

## 5. Question

Codes in both machines are the same! Just a `git clone` command line is used to get the code. So, what is the difference that make compilation with **AOT** working on a machine and failing in another machine???

Thanks,,,

Comment: We had a similar problem since 2 days which was fixed by adding `enhanced-resolve@3.3.0` in our package.json. [Ticket info](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7113).

Comment: You are my hero :)

Comment: I have the same problem, on a windows machine it works, on ubuntu 16.04 do not works...same code, same cli versions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The use of `"enhanced-resolve":"3.3.0"` is a solution for an older version of `"@angular/cli"` such as  `"1.2.3"`.

Another solution, use `"@angular/cli": "1.2.6"`

Comment: Using `"@angular/cli": "1.2.6"` fixed it. Thanks

Comment: the `@angular/cli` installed locally and globally must be the same version. In addition, the minimum version is `"1.2.6"`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng build --env=prod` instead of `ng build --prod`. When I made a brand new project and ran `ng build --prod`, I got `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'` error. But when I ran `ng build --env=prod` dist was generated fine.

Comment: `--env=prod` and `--prod` aren't the same. The most important difference is that, the `--prod` options enables `--aot`.

Comment: wow! This solved my problem when trying to create the .apk file from IONIC 3 to distribute it on Android.

Comment: using `ng build --env=prod` works because you are not using AOT in this case.